# ng repeat with <li> within a <td>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to put a list `li` inside a row of a table using `ng repeat`.

My code below of what I am trying to achieve:

```
                        <td> 
                            <div ng-repeat="x in total.count">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    {{x.key}}
                                </li>   
                            </ul>
                            </div>  
                        </td>
```

**A sample of total:**

```
"total": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "count": [
    {
      "key": "0",
      "doc_count": 83714
    },
    {
      "key": "1",
      "doc_count": 11034
    }
```

The issue is that nothing is appearing. But when I hard code the li, it works.

Can somebody advise me on how to do it in `angularjs` using `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: what is `total.count`? what is `total`

Comment: what would be your **$scope.total.count** value. can you show some sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.object = {"total": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "count": [
        {
          "key": "0",
          "doc_count": 83714
        },
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 11034
        }]
      }};
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <table border=1>
      <tr>
          <td> 
              <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="x in object.total.count">
                      {{x.key}}
                  </li>   
              </ul>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it still does not appear

Comment: An json object.. 

However, when I test it outside a td, it works. But don't know why it does not work inside a td.

Comment: Add a sample content of `total` in your question.

Comment: `total.count` is an array or object?

Comment: @Raghav: Please see edited question. I have added a sample of the json.

Comment: @jones The json you posted is not a valid one. Apart from that, there is no other issue in your code. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/2ksjf83p/1/

Comment: @jones you need to use scope variable first and then total.count for eg. `$scope.your_scope_variable.total.count`

Answer (score 1):

Try and use the ng-repeat on the li element, the ng-repeat makes a "copy" of the element its placed in. So this will repeat the list item element.

```
<td> 
    <ul>
        <li  ng-repeat="x in total.count">
            {{x.key}}
        </li>   
    </ul>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are repeating a list with one element, not the element itself